# CSS sprites vs data URIs

Tags: css, performance

I've heard a lot about the importance of using sprites in order to get your request count down. But my thinking is that rather than use sprites, you can use URIs to accomplish the same thing, and much easier (no sprite creation needed).

Is it better to use sprites or uris?

Comment: For those such as myself who didn't know what data URI was before this post, http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/06/data-uris-make-css-sprites-obsolete/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Base64-encoded data is about 1/3 larger than raw bytes, so on pages where downloading all the image data takes more than three times as long as making a request, CSS sprites are superior from a performance basis.

Also, inline data URIs make the file itself take as long to load as the actual data plus the base64-encoded images. If the data URIs are on your actual HTML page, that means rendering stops and waits for the image to load. If the data URIs are in your stylesheet, that means any rules after the data URI have to wait for it before they can be processed. On the other hand, with a sprite file, the images can load concurrently with your other resources. That may be worth the cost of one extra request, especially when you factor in the base64 penalty.

Comment: These are great points. I don't consider the 1 request that a sprite requires the drawback though. The primary drawback is having to make them, and remake them if you make edits.

Comment: hey chuck, did you do any real performance tests on the difference between using data uris vs. sprites/img in css files? Or do you know of any ressource on that topic?

Comment: "Any rules after the data URI have to wait for it before they can be processed" - You can put all your CSS sprite images in a seperate file from the rest of your CSS. This way they should be loaded in parralel.

Comment: Using compass-style.org to handle sprites can make sprite life much easier.

Comment: True there is a technical penalty for encoding as base64 but most  HTML/CSS files are gziped for delivery vs an uncompressed png or gif. There is also overhead for additional web requests. In my testing Data-URI has won my use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that support for IE5, 6 and 7 would be a good reason to use sprites over URIs, if those targets are important to you.

Comment: Therefore, if your goal is to reduce the number of requests to your pages, you should use data URIs in your main CSS file and then provide alternative sheets for <=IE7 which use sprites.

Comment: You can always use MHTML as an alternative for those browsers.